# Wordpress/Elementor Website Blazing Fast on Chrome but Laggy on Safari on Mac

Tags: wordpress, safari, elementor

I just set up my page using WordPress and Elementor and the page is very fast using Chrome. When using Safari on Mac, however, the page becomes super laggy and the CPU ramps up. I already tried using Autoptimize, W3, and Jetpack, to now avail.

Google PageSpeed says the issues lies in Javascript, however, I do not know how to optimize that. I tried using Asset CleanUp, but I already disabled all the non crucial plugins and animations.

Thanks!

The URL is: [melius.live](https://melius.live)

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your site you have three videos. Remove them and try to lazy load the iframes.
Check everything at W3 Total Cache > "User Experience".
You also can look in the Safari Inspector at Network > Waterfall to see which parts take a long time. Maybe your Mac Machine is just weak.

Comment: Thank you. The entire page already uses lazy loading so that wo't help. I cannot remove the videos as I need them (once I put the actual ones). The W3 settings were already set. I tried it on an M1 MacBook, a latest gen Intel Macbook Pro and a Macbook Air. Same issue with all of them.

Comment: The waterfall also doesn't show any clear issues. The lag is persistent even once the website is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different video plugin. More or less problem is with the Videos as it is generating code that is being blocked by the browsers.